# validate inclusion not working on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Okay I have quite a weird scenario that I do not know how to deal with so please bear with me as I try to explain it to you.

I have the following model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  Roles = { pending: 'pending_user', role2: 'role2', etc: 'etc' }
  attr_accessible :role
  validates :role, inclusion: {in: Roles.values}
  before_create :add_pendng_role #Set user role to Roles[:pending]
end
```

Now the problem is when creating a record for the first time, this validation fails! For example in my controller I have the following code:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  if @user.save  # ---------------   ALWAYS FAILS -------------------------------
    #do something
  else
    #do something else
  end
end
```

Now the reason I believe it fails is because a role is only added `before_create` which is called after the validations have passed. Now I know that I **can't replace** the `before_create :add_role`  **with** `before_validation :add_role` because I think that it will add the role each time a validation is done. The reason I can't have that is because the user role will change in the application and I don't want to reset the role each time a validations are done on the user.

Any clues on how I could tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
before_validation :add_role, on: :create
```

Comment: +1 - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html lists the callback events in order, handing reference

Comment: Sorry stupid me missed that in the reference! Thank you for all the answers

Answer (score 2):

Use *before_validation*, as explained in the [rails callback guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  Roles = { pending: 'pending_user', role2: 'role2', etc: 'etc' }
  attr_accessible :role
  validates :role, inclusion: {in: Roles.values}
  before_validation :add_pendng_role, on: :create #Set user role to Roles[:pending]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll be able to change `before_create` to `before_validation` if you use the `:on` argument:

```
before_validation :add_pendng_role, :on => :create
```